# Is it possible to load a "blank" map in iOS MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to build a mapping application that will be largely focused around custom tile overlays. Is it possible to load a map that does not contain a basemap layer, e.g. satellite or the basic map?

Desktop Apple Photos has an option to show the "grid" but that doesn't seem to exist in the [MKMapType docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmaptype). Nor can you set `map.mapType` to `nil`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played with it yet, but it looks like there are some MKTileOverlay and MKTileOverlayRenderer classes that you could experiment with?

**Edit**

I created an MKTileOverlay and added it to my mapView to successfully remove the built-in map images:

```
let tileOverlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: "")
tileOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
mapView.addOverlays([tileOverlay])
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thanks for your quick response and testing!